# servicemain function starts only at the stop of service event

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service, windows-services

I used the below link http://www.muukka.net/programming/service/Beeper%20Service.cpp to write a service. but the problem here is, the servicemain function gets called only when service stop is requested.

I want to start the servicemain function before hand, to detect usb devices connected.. what should I do for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code:

> SC_HANDLE service = CreateService( serviceControlManager, serviceName,
>   serviceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
>   **SERVICE_AUTO_START**, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, path, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

change to:

> SC_HANDLE service = CreateService( serviceControlManager, serviceName,
>   serviceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
>   **SERVICE_DEMAND_START**, SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE, path, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

Also try this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx